# PHP: What is wrong with this include?

Tags: php, include

The goal here is for the page to show a table of links to .bmp files, and if there's a .txt file with the same name in the directory, include that next to it (as it contains a brief description of what the BMP file is for, and what parts to use it with).

The only part that's not working is the include. It detects when there is a file there, as it doesn't show the "no description available". But it doesn't show the contents of the file in it's place. What am I doing wrong?

```
<table>
<tr><th>Download</th><th>Description</th><tr>
 <?php
$dir    = '/var/www/html/espruino/temp';
$files = scandir($dir,1);
function getFileExtension($filename)
{
    $path_info = pathinfo($filename);
    return $path_info['extension'];
}

foreach ($files as $filename) {
    // Construct a full path
    $filepath = $dir.'/'.$filename;
    // Is it a file? If so, get the extension using some function you created
    if(is_file($filepath)) {
        $ext = getFileExtension($filename);
        if ($ext=="bmp") {
            $infofile=substr($filepath, 0,-3)."txt";
            if (file_exists($infofile) {
                echo "<tr><td><a href='./".$filename."'>".$filename."</td><td>".include $infofile."</td></tr>";
            } else {
                echo "<tr><td><a href='./".$filename."'>".$filename."</td><td>No desciription available</td></tr>";
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

(this whole thing is embedded in a page, of course - but I figure bog-standard html isn't useful here.

Thanks - I'm still pretty new to PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use `include` like this. [From the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php):

> include returns FALSE on failure and raises a warning. Successful
> includes, unless overridden by the included file, return 1. It is
> possible to execute a return statement inside an included file in
> order to terminate processing in that file and return to the script
> which called it. Also, it's possible to return values from included
> files.

`include` specifically **does not** return the file in question. You'll need [`file_get_contents`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) or a similar mechanism for that.

Comment: Thanks - that was it. I guess I now have no idea what include is for.

Answer (score 0):

`if (file_exists($infofile) {`

you are missing the close parens:

`if (file_exists($infofile)) {`

Comment: Oops, fixed that in my code (was originally asking why my page was giving blanks, then found that, and got to the second problem.